# Alfresco Workflow form save and close

Tags: forms, workflow, alfresco

I have custom workflow where some fields are mandatory.Whenever I am saving that form,I need to fill all the mandatory field,
Is there any way where I can save form without filling mandatory field?

Answer (score 0):

You should fill the mandatory field if you have some back end logic to continue the flow after verifying that mandatory field is not null.
Otherwise you can edit mandatory tag in your respective workflow-model.xml with some like below.

```
                <target>
                    <class>cm:person</class>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </target>
```

But this will work only if you have unaffeccted user or service task.
Other solution could be hard coding default values in .bpmn file